# Where can I find the Java source code for the Vigenere cipher?

Tags: java, android, encryption, vigenere

in my app I wanted to implement some enciphering. Therefore I need the code for the Vigenere cipher. Does anyone know where I can find that source code for Java?

Comment: AFAIK it's a pretty simple cipher, why don't just implement it yourself? In fact you can check if Java Cryptography library has the implementation, anyways, I won't recommend using Vigenere cipher in real world applications.

Comment: you can find your answer here in this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280637/vigenere-cipher-in-java-for-all-utf-8-characters

Answer (score 12):

This is Vigenere cipher Class, you can use it, just call encrypt and decrypt function :
The code is from [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher#Java).

```
public class VigenereCipher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String key = "VIGENERECIPHER";
        String ori = "Beware the Jabberwock, my son! The jaws that bite, the claws that catch!";
        String enc = encrypt(ori, key);
        System.out.println(enc);
        System.out.println(decrypt(enc, key));
    }

    static String encrypt(String text, final String key) {
        String res = "";
        text = text.toUpperCase();
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char c = text.charAt(i);
            if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') continue;
            res += (char)((c + key.charAt(j) - 2 * 'A') % 26 + 'A');
            j = ++j % key.length();
        }
        return res;
    }

    static String decrypt(String text, final String key) {
        String res = "";
        text = text.toUpperCase();
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char c = text.charAt(i);
            if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') continue;
            res += (char)((c - key.charAt(j) + 26) % 26 + 'A');
            j = ++j % key.length();
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to a Vigenere Cipher Code implementation [Sample Java Code to Encrypt and Decrypt using Vigenere Cipher](http://silabsoft.org/programming/java-implementation-of-the-vigenere-cipher/), besides that I cannot recommend to use Vigenere Cipher as encryption.

I recommend [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/).

Comment: The link you posted is now dead.

Comment: @GeoGriffin Thanks for pointing out, I have updated the link to another example.

Comment: link dead again.

Answer (score 1):

[This pos](http://www.cipherbase.co.in/2014/02/breaking-vigenere-cipher-java.html)t will help you .The entire code for deciphering is provided. You can use this for writing enciphering code